# How to install TCP application on INET host (omnetpp)?

Tags: networking, routes, client, simulation, omnet++

I have a TCP Application module built as "ClientSideApplication". I need to install this application on an AODVRouter host "host". I can not figure out a way to do that.

In my omnetpp.ini file i have,

```
**.host[*].numTcpApps = 1
**.host[*].tcpApp[*].typename = "ClientSideApplication"
**.host[*].tcpApp[*].active = true
**.host[*].tcpApp[*].localAddress = ""
**.host[*].tcpApp[*].localPort = -1
**.host[*].tcpApp[*].connectAddress = "ideHost"
**.host[*].tcpApp[*].connectPort = 1000
**.host[*].tcpApp[*].tOpen = 0.5s
```

But i am not sure that if it is enough, because when i am seeing the simulation, there is a "waiting" (text) written on the top of the Application Module. Can you guys tell me the way to install the TCP app and make it work with AODVRouter host ("host").

> Note: I have implemented the TCP Application module as an extension of TCPAppBase and used the example of TCPSessionApp from inet source folder.

Comment: Could you post some details on what the `.ned` file (for AODVRouter) looks like? Is the tcpApp correctly associated (are tcpIn and tcpOut connected to something)? Also, not directly related, but I found [here](http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/wiki/Omnet%2B%2B_Tutorial) it is written that TCPSessionApp does not really scale well because it doesn't use message passing.